# Appending controls to Page in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In web forms site I would previously be able to append controls to the head of a page using:

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
page.Header.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Is there a similar approach possible when using MVC? As we use this helper method a lot for injecting controls to a page.

#### Scenarios

1. For example I have a page which renders a list of news articles, I then want to inject a link element to the page header to the rss feed for the articles.
2. When displaying paging we display append a rel link to the head

   link href="/news/?page=2" rel="next" />

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Do you mean `PartialViews`?

Comment: Can you describe the situation where you would need this? Can't you use jquery?

Comment: I've added some scenarios.